# php file_put_contents no such file or directory occasionally

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I start 8 processes to execute a job, the code in the job like this:

```
<?php
$dir = "/home/test/fileputcontents/0";
if(! is_dir($dir)){
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}
file_put_contents("{$dir}/0.txt", "aaaa\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

but it raises an error which say "No such file or directory" sometimes，not very offen, thanks very much.

Is it because php_mkdir_ex method? Multi-process create directory at the same time.

```
/* DEPRECATED APIs: Use php_stream_mkdir() instead */
PHPAPI int php_mkdir_ex(const char *dir, zend_long mode, int options)
{
    int ret;

    if (php_check_open_basedir(dir)) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((ret = VCWD_MKDIR(dir, (mode_t)mode)) < 0 && (options & REPORT_ERRORS)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "%s", strerror(errno));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with muli-processes? the php version is 7.4.5，CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)，GNU coreutils 8.22                                                           November 2016

Comment: Is there anything else in the script? Why do you need to create the directory every time? Maybe you removed some of the code to make it easier to post, but it is part of what causes the error?

Comment: Yes, The sript is used to export mysql data to file。before write to the file, It checkout dir every time

Comment: @noam， I removed "create directories recursively"，Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason from php source code. It's because the directory creation collision. For example:

1. We have 2 processes to create directory "/home/test/fileputcontents/0" at the same time.
2. Now only `/home` directory exists, we need create `test/fileputcontents/0`
3. One process (we call A) has created `test`, is going to create `fileputcontents`，anther process (we call B) is going to create `test` again, but it already exists.
4. Then process B stopping creating directory, because it thinks all directories exist
5. When B tries to call `file_put_contents` before A creates all the directories, then it warns `"No such file or directory"`, because `fileputcontents/0` does not exist.

My solution, create directories because processes start.

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=35326

Comment: Oh.. fixed in 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Are all 8 processes running at the same time and writing to the same file? If two processes would write in the file at the same moment, it could be possible that the file is locked (caused by the LOCK_EX flag). So one process would win (can write to the file) and the other one would not wait, instead an error would be raised.

Comment: 8 processes write different files, but in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in 8.1

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/7383

```
- if (ret < 0) {
+ if (ret < 0 && errno != EEXIST) {
```